# How to configure tls with traefik in kubernetes using yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-ingress, traefik

I am having trouble exposing a service over http and https using traefik 2.9 in Kubernetes.
The http endpoint kinda works, I introduced CORS errors somehow once I tried to add https but that is not my main concern. The https ingress is broken and I cant find any indication of why its not working. The traefik pod doesn't log any errors and the dotnet service isn't receiving the requests. Also both routes show up in the dashboard and websecure is displayed as having TLS enabled.

Excluding ClusterRole, ServiceAccount, and ClusterRoleBinding because I believe that's configured correctly as the http route wouldn't work if it wasnt.

Traefik config:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-deployment
  labels:
    app: traefik
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: traefik
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefik
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-account
      containers:
        - name: traefik
          image: traefik:v2.9
          args:
            - --api.insecure
            - --providers.kubernetesingress
            - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
            - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
            - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 80
            - name: dashboard
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: websecure
              containerPort: 443
```

Traefik services:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-dashboard-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: dashboard
  selector:
    app: traefik
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 10.10.1.38
  ports:
    - targetPort: web
      port: 80
      name: http
    - targetPort: websecure
      port: 443
      name: https
  selector:
    app: traefik
```

Secret for tls:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  comptech.pem: <contents of pem file base64 encoded>
  comptech.crt: <contents of crt file base64 encoded>
  comptech.key: <contents of key file base64 encoded>
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: comptech-cert
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
```

Service for dotnet application:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: control-api-service
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 5000
      protocol: TCP
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 5000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: control-api
```

Ingresses:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: control-api-ingress
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web
spec:
  rules:
  - host: sub.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: control-api-service
            port:
              name: http

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: control-api-secure-ingress
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: websecure
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: sub.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: control-api-service
            port:
              name: https
    tls:
  - secretName: comptech-cert
```

My hope here is that someone with much more experience with traefik/tls will be able to quickly realize what I'm doing incorrectly. Any input is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
The firewall was only allowing http traffic, we reconfigured it to support https and it is responding with Traefiks default certs. So i can hit the container but tls is still not configured using my supplied cert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The pem file is not needed and the crt file was generated incorrectly using openssl the command that worked for me was: `openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile comptech.pem | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -out cert.crt`
- Pointing to the https port of the control-api-service was not working and needed to be changed to http
- A config map needed to be created for the traefik deployment to work correctly:

> ```
> apiVersion: v1 kind: ConfigMap metadata:   name: traefik-config   labels:
>     name: traefik-config   namespace: default data:   dyn.yaml: |
>     # https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/https/tls/
>     tls:
>       stores:
>         default:
>           defaultCertificate:
>             certFile: '/certs/tls.crt'
>             keyFile: '/certs/tls.key'
> ```

- Finally the configmap and secret must be used in the traefik deployment like below:

> ```
> kind: Deployment
> apiVersion: apps/v1
> metadata:
>   name: traefik-deployment
>   labels:
>     app: traefik
> spec:
>   replicas: 1
>   selector:
>     matchLabels:
>       app: traefik
>   template:
>     metadata:
>       labels:
>         app: traefik
>     spec:
>       serviceAccountName: traefik-account
>       containers:
>         - name: traefik
>           image: traefik:v2.9
>           args:
>             - --api.insecure
>             - --providers.kubernetesingress
>             - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
>             - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
>             - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls
>             - --providers.file.filename=/config/dyn.yaml
>           ports:
>             - name: web
>               containerPort: 80
>             - name: dashboard
>               containerPort: 8080
>             - name: websecure
>               containerPort: 443
>           volumeMounts:
>             - name: comptech-cert-volume
>               mountPath: /certs
>             - name: traefik-config-volume
>               mountPath: /config
>       volumes:
>         - name: comptech-cert-volume
>           secret:
>             secretName: comptech-cert
>         - name: traefik-config-volume
>           configMap:
>             name: traefik-config
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In my setup, I use the IngressRoute CRD implementation from Traefik.
The CRDs were automatically installed when I setup the Traefik controller using Helm.

Is it a possibility for you to use this in your setup? You can check if the CRDs already exist using below command on your k8s cluster.

```
kubectl get crd
```

Below is a snippet from one of my projects where I also use a custom wildcard certificate from a secret using the IngressRoute manifest.

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: blue-api-ingressroute
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: "Host(`blue.domain.com`)" && PathPrefix(`/swagger`)"
      kind: Rule
      services:
      - name: blue-api-svc
        port: 80
  tls:
    secretName: bluecert
```

You can also include other custom resources that are available from Traefik. The complete set of configuration that is available can be seen [here](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/). For example, below is the same snippet with middleware and tlsoptions resources included for improving the security of the endpoint.

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: TLSOption
metadata:
  name: tlsoptions
spec:
  minVersion: VersionTLS12
  cipherSuites:
    - TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    - TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305
    - TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305
    - TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305
    - TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    - TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    - TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    - TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV
  curvePreferences:
    - CurveP521
    - CurveP384
  sniStrict: true
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: security
spec:
  headers:
    frameDeny: true
    sslRedirect: true
    browserXssFilter: true
    contentTypeNosniff: true
    stsIncludeSubdomains: true
    stsPreload: true
    stsSeconds: 31536000
---     
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: blue-api-ingressroute
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: "Host(`blue.domain.com`)" && PathPrefix(`/swagger`)"
      kind: Rule
      services:
      - name: blue-api-svc
        port: 80
      middlewares:
      - name: security
  tls:
    secretName: bluecert
    options:
      name: tlsoptions
```